# Can't style an element in a td

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to style the h3 and p tags, but I couldn't. I tried class, id, divs, and spans, yet to no avail. I'm also kind of new to coding, so I'm sorry for the poor indentation.

```css
h3, p {
 color:#2c6ffe; 
}
```

```html
<tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <u><h3>Introduction:</h3></u>
            <p><i>To Kill A Mockingbird</i> is a coming of age novel that was 
            written by Harper Lee. The story To Kill A Mockingbird is not based on 
            a true story but references in Harper Lee’s daily life. The book was 
            written in at the time of the Great Depression and the Jim Crow laws, 
            taking place in the early 1930s. The story takes place in Maycomb, 
            Alabama, and is narrated by the main character, a little girl named 
            Jean Louise “Scout” Finch. Scout’s father, Atticus Finch, is a lawyer 
            with high moral standards.The book is an accurate representation of 
            racism and discrimination towards black people in early 1900s. Scout, 
            who happens to be the protagonist of the story, is also the narrator 
            as the story is seen through her eyes and explained through her 
            thoughts.</p>
         </td>
```

Comment: Can you also share the CSS?

Comment: You should post the code from those examples you tried and explain specifically what is confusing you about each one.

Comment: I've tried adding a div and styling it, but the declarations wouldn't be applied. Same thing with giving the td a class or id. I've also tried to give the  h3 and p tags a class or id, but it also wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the entire `<tr></tr>` with `<table></table>`?
Are you getting any error messages in the console when you press F12 (for DevTools)?

Try copy pasting your html into Codepen.io and seeing if it works there
You can also try being more specific with your query selector for example

```
table > h3{ color: black;}
```

Or if all else fails, Inline-styles

```
<h3 style="color: black;">Mockingbird</h3>
```

Also this is not great practice but applying the !important tag in CSS may solve some cascading issue.

```
h3{ color: pink !important}
```

Comment: It was a cascading issue, thanks so much for the helpful answer!